# replace CommandBuilder with ADO.NET classic commands

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

what is the best option to replace,in .NET Framework 4,CommandBuilder from a code like that,there are about 100 fields,with ADO.NET classic commands? CommandBuilder has performance issues over slow network connections like Vpn

```
        wConn = New FbConnection("...")
        wConn.Open()
        wCmd = New FbCommand("SELECT * FROM ..", wConn)
        wCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        wFbADA = New FbDataAdapter(wCmd)
        wFbCbuild = New FbCommandBuilder(wFbADA)
    
        wFbADA.Fill(tbl)
        
       For Each rw In tbl.rows
          ......................
              many calculations over tbl fields
          .....................
        Next
    
        wFbADA.InsertCommand = wFbCbuild.GetInsertCommand
        wFbADA.UpdateCommand = wFbCbuild.GetUpdateCommand
        wFbADA.DeleteCommand = wFbCbuild.GetDeleteCommand
        wFbADA.Update(tbl)
```

I've debug the code and the slowest part is when calling:

```
wFbADA.InsertCommand = wFbCbuild.GetInsertCommand
wFbADA.UpdateCommand = wFbCbuild.GetUpdateCommand
wFbADA.DeleteCommand = wFbCbuild.GetDeleteCommand
```

I could try to loop by table and check RowState:

```
 For Each rw As DataRow In tb.Rows 
   Select Case rw.RowState 
           Case DataRowState.Added
              'run insert command
           Case DataRowState.Modified
              'run update command
           Case DataRowState.Deleted
              'run delete command  
   End Select
  Next
```

Comment: CommandBuilder has very little impact on overall performance. It sucks as an API, but that's a completely different topic. The ADO.NET commands that CommandBuilder will end up issuing will be fairly similar to what you would issue, or any other tool would issue. If you want to try a different tool, then consider an ORM or Dapper or something.

Comment: Here is an example of creating your UpdateCommand manually. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters#example  Are you sure you want to write out all 100 field names and parameters without any errors?

Comment: @Mary:yes I'll rewrite the code, I made a test for 30 fields for one record insert/update and classic ado net command is 4 times faster than CommandBuilder.the slowest part of code is when calling:  wFbCbuild.GetInsertCommand, wFbCbuild.GetUpdateCommand,wFbCbuild.GetDeleteCommand

Comment: You will also need the Insert and Delete. I just provided the Update as an example. The other 2 would be done the same way.

Comment: @Mary: what is the purpose of parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original? (I didn't used it).Add your first comment as an answer to mark it as resolved,thanks!

Comment: Here is a C# answer about `DataRowVersion`. Would be the same in vb.net. Thanks for the offer but link only answers really belong in comments. Glad it is resolved.

Comment: Oops! the link didn't get added. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/whats-the-purpose-of-the-sqlparametersourceversion

Comment: please add an aswer.thanks